# Javascript not working in Safari when navigating to a new url

Tags: javascript, django, twitter-bootstrap, safari, navigation

When taking bill payment I display a static bootstrap popup to tell the user to wait.  The user clicks a button which calls the js function to display the popup, then redirect the user to the url that runs the billing on the server side.  It works in all browsers except Safari.  When I click the button in Safari the popup does not appear, it just navigates to the billing page.  I noticed if I remove the navigation line (location.replace('/billingpage/pay/');) the popup will display properly in safari.  It seems like if there is a navigation in the javascript safari does not bother displaying the popup.

I also tried putting the navigation in another function and calling it after a timeout like this: window.setTimeout(navigate(), 1000); but that did not work either.

```js
function pay_now() {
  document.getElementById("paynow_btn").disabled=true;
  document.getElementById("paynow_btn").style.opacity = 0.25;
  var wait_title = "Please wait while the transaction is processed...";
  var wait_message = "<br/><br/><br/><br/> ";
  document.getElementById("staticModalLabel").innerHTML = wait_title;
  document.getElementById("staticModalBody").innerHTML = wait_message;
  var spinner = new Spinner().spin();
  document.getElementById("staticModalBody").appendChild(spinner.el);
  $('#staticPopupModal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
  });
  location.replace('/billingpage/pay/');
}
```

```html
 <a href="javascript:pay_now();" id="paynow_btn" class="btn btn-green">PAY</a>
```

Comment: should have tried `window.setTimeout(navigate, 1000);` - with `navigate()` you're calling the function immediately and passing its *result* to `setTimeout()`

Comment: Thank you Pointy, that actually fixed it.  Now I am just curious if there is a way to do this without the timeout at all.  It does seem like a timing issue with the way Safari interprets the javascript.

Comment: It's not so much a *timing* issue as it as an issue of what the browser knows about the event it's working on. By using a timeout (and it'll probably work with a delay value of 0 instead of 1000), you put that page reload into a separate event thread.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't that is the expected behaviour on every javascript process?
Anyway, In your case, I would definitely go with jquery deferred and promise. this is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanchaz/x6g4yb1s/) i have put to make a modal dialog with jqueryui.

basically it goes like this in code.

```
var dfd = $.Deferred();

$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "go to billing page": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            dfd.resolve();
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            dfd.reject();
        }
    }
});

$.when(dfd).then(

function () {
    alert('go to billing page');
},

function () {
    alert('nope');
});
```